# ASP .NET Ajax examples for the beginner

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

Hi I am looking for some good collection of examples on AJAX in ASP.Net. Please share some excellent links, also if you think there is a good resource which can help me learning - please share it. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The official ASP.NET site is a great resource...

http://www.asp.net/ajax/ - Site

http://www.asp.net/learn/ajax-videos/ - Videos

http://www.asp.net/learn/ajax/ - Tutorials

Answer (score 2):

Good to use AJAX control Toolkit,,,,From this link, you will example of each AJAX control toolkit...
http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples