# How to make javascript interact with .aspx page?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, ajax

I wish to run some asp.net code on a page generated by Wordpress. Is there a way using `XMLHttpRequest()` to make JavaScript interact with .aspx page just like a Servlet?

For example, I hope that I can do this in JavaScript:

```
xmlHttpRequest.open("POST", "http ://some.aspx", true);
send_request("request=add,1,2");
function getReadyStateHandler(xmlHttpRequest) {
    //handle_response
}
```

How to write and configure such an asp page? Does someone know a good tutorial?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASp.net Ajax examples for the beginner](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102941/asp-net-ajax-examples-for-the-beginner)

Answer (score 0):

You are better of using JQuery for this task.

It is Javascipt library that has [exactly functionality that you re looking for](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)
You can call your backend methods to invoke serverside action that would return [JSON object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.json.jsonobject%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). and then in done function process the result.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body
}).done(function(result) {
var dataFromTheSreverside = result;
  $( this ).addClass( "done" );
});
```

[Here you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102941/asp-net-ajax-examples-for-the-beginner) can find a lot of examples